# Переключение чекбокса

Tags: php

На странице есть чекбокс

```
<input class="switch__input" name="2fa" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox">
```

Как обработать его переключение? Пытаюсь данным макаром, но таблица в БД не обновляется.

```
if(isset($_POST['2fa'])) {
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE user SET фact='true' WHERE id='$sesion_id'");
} else { 

}
```

Comment: `фact` - У вас прям так в БД? Зачем? А по вопросу - так что не понятного-то? Что именно не так

Comment: @Manitikyl  act*. Непонятно почему не работает, ну т.е у меня чекбокс в виде свитчера и когда я переключаю его, то значения в БД не меняется

Comment: Так судя по тому что я вижу, у вас нет переключения, вы после `else` добавьте запрос, и попробуйте

Comment: @Manitikyl толку нет, добавил в условие else выставление значения на false, но ничего не происходит, вообще

Comment: Как можно сделать сохранение чекбокса в прошлом положении? Т.е он сбрасывается при перезагрузке страницы